# Checking for extended desktop using Batch Files

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

evening all

looking for some advise, how would one go about using a batch file to check if a desktop is set to Extended without the use of 3rd party applications or PowerShell.

all the googling I've done so far all suggests other applications, however I cannot do that as the hardware is not allow any 3rd part aps on it.

I've been googling for hours and seem to have hit a brick wall with this. so looking to see if anyone has any out of the box ideas that may help me.

i must insist it has to be called from a batch script and no 3rd party apps

tried WMIC to see if theres any options there to no avail, i did consider using this and counting active monitors but this doesnt guarentee that if it does that its on extended desktop

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi  path WmiMonitorBasicDisplayParams  get Active
```

this doesnt work on windows 7  as i get a error stating

```
Description = not supported
```

any ideas will be helpful

Comment: Please add tags for the operating system and version you are referring to!

Comment: amended and ive also now posted my own solution

Answer (score 0):

After breaking this down and running some tests by ripping and comparing the registry's, I now know that the machines with 2 screens and extended desktops vs machines that have 1 screen have a difference at the following registry location

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Connectivit
y\
```

machines with 2 screens and extended desktop enabled have the following registry key

`"eXtend"`

Where as the single screen machines do not. I'm going to use this to detect if the machine has extended, use displayswitch.exe /clone to set it to duplicate do the changes I need to and once completed change it back to extended with displayswitch.exe /extend.

This solves my issue and hopefully its helps some else out who may need to do this (not likely but you never know)